# Is there a way to match the height of list elements?

Tags: css, html, list, css-tables

I have an un-ordered list, there are 3 li items per line and 5 lines. The content of each li is dynamic and if their is more content in 1 li item then the others it will push all li items after it down. Is there a way to stop this happening, so if an li has more content then each li on that line will match it's height and thus making everything line up?

I've included a link to the code - http://jsfiddle.net/3YTbK/4/

And I've found this which makes everything line up, but I now need to figure out how to stretch the height of the in line elements:

```
ul > li:nth-child(3n+1) {
clear: both;}
```

Also I'd ideally like to use only a CSS solution

Comment: Show us the relevant code (HTML and CSS). I suggest you upload your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: not without splitting them into seperate uls or using some javascript

Comment: I've added the code above :)

Comment: Is there anything to say against using a `table`?

Comment: @tim Unless your table contains exactly 2 columns (topping, price), then a table element is inappropriate here.

Comment: I considered using a table, but as the site is responsive, depending on the screen size, the amount of cells per row will change, and i'd have to make a few different tables for each screen then.

Comment: @user1140942: just so that I can try something, how would you be changing the amount of cells per row depending on screen-size? the width alloted for each `li` is 33.33% so there will be 3 `li` elements per row right?

Comment: @Harry: I'll be changing it by changing the percent width, yeah thats right it's 33.33%, on a mobile, each cell will be 50%.